# Is it possible to have a script built-in into a custom resource?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Here's a rudimentary custom resource:

```
extends Resource

export(Resource) var scr
```

I can drag a pre-made .gd script into this exported property in Inspector, and it works as intended. I can click on the exported property field and embed a resource (like "New ShaderMaterial"), and it would also work as intended, and I would be able to edit that sub-resource normally. However, if I click on the exported property and select "New GDScript", there doesn't seem to be a way to open the new gdscript for editing. Is it possible to embed a gdscript sub-resource the same way you can embed a different sub-resource?

Comment: Could you tell me of an example use-case for this? I am having a hard time understanding what can be achieved with this.

Comment: Let the custom resource represent a consumable item. It contains normal item fields, like price, weight, inventory icon, etc, but also a script of what would happen should you consume it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Godot does not provide any GUI for this, but it *is* possible. When you add a `GDScript` to your resource, you will see that it is given a path within the resource file:

[image]

If you crack open `new_resource.tres` in a text editor, you'll see the following:

```
[gd_resource type="Resource" load_steps=3 format=2]

[ext_resource path="res://MyResource.gd" type="Script" id=1]

[sub_resource type="GDScript" id=1]

[resource]
script = ExtResource( 1 )
scr = SubResource( 1 )
```

You can write your script under the `GDScript` `sub_resource` like so:

```
[sub_resource type="GDScript" id=1]
script/source = "extends Spatial

func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.
"
```

This feels rather hacky, so you might consider [submitting a proposal](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals) if this workflow is important to you.

Comment: Granted, I haven't used Godot in a while, but isn't there already an option to embed the GDScript into the resource from the dialog that pops up when you attach a new script file? I'm almost certain I've done this before, without requiring workarounds.

Comment: @flesk I believe the "attach script" dialog only appears when you attach a script to a `Node`, not when you assign one to an `export`ed field. I'd be delighted to be proven wrong though :)